# Using dimensional analysis to evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}x^n$

Tags: proof-verification, dimensional-analysis

Let $x$ have dimensions $[L]$ of length, so that $dx$ also has dimension $[L]$. Then $$\frac{d(x^n)}{dx}\;\text{has dimension}\;\frac{[L]^n}{[L]}=[L]^{n-1}.$$ Therefore $$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=cx^{n-1}$$ for some (dimensionless) constant $c$.

Disregarding the fact that $c$ is undetermined (bonus: can anyone derive it using dimensional analysis?), I am wondering: is this proof valid?

Comment: Of course, the validity of treating $dy/dx$ as a fraction is a separate issue, not germane to the question.

Comment: Well, the function $\sin(x) / x$ is also dimensionless, so why isn't the answer $c x^{n-1} \frac{\sin x}{x}$? There are lots of dimensionless functions of a single variable, and any one of them can multiply the answer without changing the units... so your proof leaves me unconvinced.

Comment: @John The sine function takes as input a dimensionless real number (or, in some systems, it has an "orientation" - in any case, it is not dimensionless there). So the expression $\sin x$ does not make sense in this context.

Comment: Not valid but just lucky that you picked $x^n$.

Comment: I'm wondering if this would be a better fit at Physics, or if they would tell you that it's obviously correct.

Comment: I think $n$ is the only value that $c$ can have for which the linear operator on polynomials in $x$ that takes each $x^n$ to $cx^{n-1}$ is shift-equivariant.

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{d}{d(x\text{ feet})} (x\text{ feet})^n = \frac{d}{d(12x\text{ inches})} (12x\text{ inches})^n = 12^{n-1} \frac{d}{d(x\text{ inches})} (x\text{ inches})^n.$  I started an answer with this, but I'll need to think about it a bit more.

Comment: _If_ we disregard the fact that $c$ is undetermined, I think it's perfectly valid. Dimensional analysis will always give the answer correct to a constant of proportionality, in the sense that if all the independent parameters are known then a relation can be derived/validated. As far as $c$ is concerned, there is no way dimensional analysis will help there. How do we calculate Planck's constant or Avogadro number from it? (They are defined for this universe, and maybe different for a different universe ;))
@JavierBadia I, too, feel this is a better fit at Physics. Wait. Is the sentence proper?

Comment: @tpb261: I feel like the issue here, this being a man site and all, is showing that you can't make a non-constant dimensionless function out of only $ x $. For all we know, there might be a constant $ a $ with dimensions of length such that $ c =x/a $.

Comment: You may be interested in Buckingham's theorem.

Comment: @nayrb: Yes it's a useful theorem that helps the heuristic called dimensional analysis, but note the assumptions in that theorem, which we do not have in mathematics and hence do not apply to this question at all.

Comment: The dimensionality of $dx$ is not $\mathcal{L}$. It is zero.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: There's nothing wrong with what you wrote, but it is circular because you are essentially using the property of the derivative of $x^n$ with respect to $x$ for the second equality. Also, there are other assumptions as I stated in my answer.

Comment: @user21820 : You're mistaken.  I wasn't using that at all.  I was merely canceling $12^n$ in the numerator with $12$ in the denominator.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Ok I see you were using the infinitesimals, in which case there are other possible objections, although I do find the necessary assumptions reasonable enough. Of course I still don't accept it as a sufficient **justification** since it begs too many questions.

Comment: @Arkamis : How do you get that?  If $y$ is in meters and $x$ is in seconds, then $dy/dx$ is in meters per second.  That wouldn't be true if the dimensionality of $dx$ were not seconds.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You can see Arkamis' comments responding to me for his view of why he said that. I don't agree, but I see an indeed valid point that some assumptions are necessary to say that the dimensions of the secant approximations carry over to the limit. Perhaps you can give a better reason for that assumption to him than I.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My argument is that the dimensionality of neither $dx$ *nor* $dy$ can be specified. Of course $dy/dx$ is in meters per second, but I do not agree that we can prescribe dimensionality to $dx$ or $dy$. Instead, the derivative is an operator that reduces dimensionality by 1, just as the integral is an operator that increases dimensionality by 1. If we want to prescribe dimensionality to $dy$ and $dx$ *ex post facto* once we develop a physical model, I see no issue with that. However, I cannot justify leading with that claim and attempting to use it to prove things about derivatives.

Comment: @Arkamis : If the derivative "reduces dimensionality by $1$", then when $y$ is in meters and $x$ is in seconds, and $dy/dx$ is in meters per second, then meters per second must be $1$ less than$\ldots\ldots$what? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I was out of space; it reduces the dimensionality of the independent variable by 1 -- position with respect to time has time-dimension 0. Taking the derivative reduces the time dimension to -1, doing so again reduces it to -2 and so forth. The same arguments can hold under, say, fractional differentiation and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite a proof due to the fact that it gives no information about $c$, the only thing you can say is that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} x^n = c(x) x^{n-1} $$

by unit analysis [an example is $c(x) = \sin( x/L)$ where $L$ has units of length]. In this form we have no idea what $c(x)$ should be, and really can't say anything about the function.

Edit: Note that $c(x)$ is unit-less.

Comment: But even what you are saying is not even anything because $c(x)$ could be $\frac{f(x)}{x^{n-1}}$ for any function $f$ such that $f(x)$ has dimension $L^{n-1}$, which is what we started with!

Comment: It could be, that's why you can't say anything about the function like I said.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying. Then we're perfectly agreed. =)

Comment: $c$ has to be a constant. There is no constant $L$ with units of length which can be used in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a function $f$ has the property that $f(\alpha x)=\alpha^n f(x)$ for all $\alpha$. Then $f(x)=cx^n$ for some constant $c$.

Now take a plot the graph of $y=x^n$ and scale it by a factor of $\alpha$ in the horizontal direction and by a factor of $\alpha^n$ in the vertical direction. The above property means you end up with the same graph you started with.

Now imagine a tangent line drawn on the graph at the point $(x,x^n)$. Scaling graphs doesn't change the fact that a tangent line is a tangent. So the tangent becomes the tangent at $(\alpha x,\alpha^nx^n)$.

But what happens to the gradient of a line if you scale a graph? If you scale by $\alpha$ horizontally and $\beta$ vertically the gradient is scaled by $\beta/\alpha$. So the gradient is scaled by $\alpha^{n-1}$ in this case.

In other words, the gradient at $(\alpha x, \alpha^nx)$ is the same as the gradient at $(x, x^n)$ scaled by $\alpha^{n-1}$.

So the gradient of $f$, $f'$, has the property that $f'(\alpha x)=\alpha^{n-1}f'(x)$.

So $f'(x)=cx^{n-1}$.

But what does this have to do with what you said? Dimension arguments are arguments about scaling in disguise. You can see this if you imagine plotting a graph of some physical quantity using some units for the scales. If you switch to different units your graph will get scaled. But fundamentally, changing units doesn't really change anything, and this fact means that when you scale your graph there are still going to be features that remain unchanged. Describing this in full generality will require more space than I have here but the argument above is one specific example.

Here's a mathematical (but high level and tricky) discussion of this subject by Terry Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/

In other words, your argument is valid, but only if you've previously proved the properties you need from dimensional analysis.

Comment: Note that Terence's blog post is about formalizing dimensional analysis, with different assumptions needed for different formalizations, and not about "using dimensions to reason about pure mathematics", which you claimed earlier in your comment to my answer. Moreover it is ridiculous to try to prove a completely mathematical phenomenon by appealing to heuristics used in physics, which themselves rely on a lot of assumptions. So the argument is essentially useless because those assumptions cannot be proven without essentially solving the original question.

Comment: Furthermore, your argument given at the start of your answer is incomplete because you didn't in the first place prove that the derivative exists, and so cannot claim to be able to draw a tangent line. Even then, it is a better argument than the flawed argument supposedly using dimensional analysis.

Comment: You don't need to prove everything from scratch. When students first compute derivatives of monomials they often do the product rule first so they know monomials will have derivatives before they compute them. As for not appealing to heuristics, my entire PhD was based on using heuristics from physics to prove mathematical results, once they were appropriately formalised. Dimensional analysis is completely formalisable in mathematics.

Comment: The product rule, as you say, is one way to know that, but my point is simply that the asker may be completely unaware of all these unstated assumptions or usage of other theorems, and it is then quite misleading to simply say that dimensional analysis is a valid proof. Of course, if you first **prove** some theorems (that may correspond to dimensional analysis) you can then use them, but we shouldn't leave out important dependencies that are after all the crux of the matter. The question was about proving a fact so much more basic than these details that it would be wrong to omit them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid, for the reasons that *TylerHG* and *Javier Badia* already alluded to in their comments. For example we could use your reasoning to say that if $v$ has dimension $L$, and $c$ is some physical constant also with dimension $L$, then $\frac{d(\sqrt{c^2-v^2})}{dv}$ has no dimension and hence is some constant. The problem is that dimensional analysis is merely a heuristic and doesn't take constants into account. Moreover, it discards information about the function, and so your argument gives the right answer for only $x^n$. Lest you think this kind of function is contrived, it in fact appears in relativitistic formulae where $c$ is of course the speed of light.

[Edit: As requested, I'll try to specify more precisely what is wrong with the argument and what is needed to make it correct.]

One objection to the above counter-example might be that it has more than one variable or constant. But there is still another problem with the argument, which is that there is no a priori reason to suppose that $x^n$ is physically meaningful when $x$ has some dimension $L$, and ${L}$ is not a dependent set ($x$ is not dimensionless). Under both those assumptions, the only possible physically meaningful dimensionless functions of $x$ are the dimensionless constant functions, and hence the only possible physically meaningful functions of $x$ that have dimension $L^k$ are of the form $cx^k$ for some constant $c$. For this to apply to the original question you have to justify why you think $x^n$ is physically meaningful for each $n$, otherwise it is not a valid proof.

In case one might think that the assumptions stated above are obviously valid ones, one should consider say $x^\pi$ or $x^{1000}$. Are they really physically meaningful? If not, how can one use physical units to argue anything about the behaviour of the mathematical functions? If one thinks that the result should simply hold for any $n$ since it holds for some like $1,2,3$, then it's already a fallacy. And even if it holds for all rational $n$, there is still no reason to think that it holds for irrational $n$. All these properties come about because of the **mathematical** nature of such functions, not **physical**.

Comment: To the contrary, we have *two* numbers involved here which carry dimensions - for example, any ratio $c/v$ (to any power) is therefore dimensionless. We *cannot* conclude that the answer is a dimensionless constant; in fact, we can conclude very little because of having two dimensioned quantities. (By the way, the correct answer $-v/\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$ is dimensionless, as dim. analysis predicts.)

Comment: No dimensional analyst would claim that your expression is constant because it has no dimension. There is a dimensioned constant in your expression, $c$. If you account for your dimensioned constants correctly dimensional analysis isn't just a heuristic.

Comment: @NotNotLogical: What do you mean by dimension? I was using "dimension" to refer to units, which is exactly what Buckingham's theorem uses. Note that that theorem in fact precisely states its assumption that only multiplication between quantities is allowed, and the units involved are independent, neither of which you have in your question.

Comment: @DanPiponi: I don't know what you mean. I specified that both $v$ and $c$ have the same dimension. And I said that **if we used** the argument by *NotNotLogical* we can say that since the answer has no dimensions it must be proportional to the $0$-th power of $v$, which is obviously wrong as he himself gives the correct answer. Notice that all dimensional analysis is able to predict is that the answer indeed has no dimension, which is in the first place obvious from the definition of derivative.

Comment: @user21820 "the answer has no dimensions": correct. "it must be proportional to the $0$-th power of $v$": false. It must have no dimensions. There are many ways to combine $c$ and $v$ to get a dimensionless function (as I said, $c/v$ is an example candidate).

Comment: @NotNotLogical: Exactly my point, which is why you cannot conclude about the derivative of $x^n$ with respect to $x$ using dimensional analysis!! In particular, you do not get a **constant** $c$ but a dimension-less **function** $c$ that you cannot say anything else about, as *Jeb* said.

Comment: @user21820 The case of $x^n$ is different though. It does not involve any additional (dimensioned) constants like $c$ which can cause problems. The only dimension involved is due to $x$. (And I'm not sure the introduction of a new variable $L$, as in Jeb's answer, is entirely valid, although it's an interesting objection.)

Comment: @NotNotLogical: But that's precisely the problem! For example, in physics we 'know' that the speed of light is constant, but what if it is actually a function of speed? Then there is only one actual variable quantity, velocity $v$, but your argument would give the wrong answer.

Comment: @user21820 I'm not sure what you're getting at. When multiple dimensioned quantities are involved (variable or constant), we can conclude little with dimensional analysis. My question is about the special case of there being only _one_ dimensioned variable. But perhaps I am misunderstanding you - please edit your answer if you think you could elaborate on some of these points, so that your example is as clear as possible!

Comment: @NotNotLogical: I've added to my answer. I hope it is clear now. By the way I did not state assumptions that dimensional analysis itself requires, such as that a dimensionless function that depends on no variables or constants must be constant.

Comment: "how can one use physical units to argue anything about the behaviour of the mathematical functions?" Physical units are no less mathematical than dimensionless numbers. What else could they be? They are quantities with formal rules for manipulation just like the rest of mathematics. With formal rules come theorems. See here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/ Tao is using dimensions to reason about pure mathematics.

Comment: @DanPiponi: Your so-called formal rules include precisely the kind of assumptions that I stated explicitly in my answer. You cannot simply say that you choose any formal rules you like and play games with symbols using them and expect me to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the formal definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Suppose that we could apply dimensional analysis under this operation. Then,

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c_1 \operatorname{dim}(f(x+h)) - c_1\operatorname{dim}(f(x))}{c_2 \operatorname{dim}(h)}.$$

Dimensionally speaking, the relation $x\propto \mathcal{U} \implies x = ku$ holds for every constant $k$. Therefore, we could use this definition to show that the derivative is any ratio we desire: $\frac{c_1}{c_2}$. This is nonsensical.

The reason this fails is because dimensionality must be *finite* and *nonzero*. Zero pounds is the same as zero meters -- zero is zero; it is a dimensionally-annihilating quantity. $dx$ does not have dimensionality $\mathcal{L}$, since $dx$, depending on how we treat it, is smaller than any finite quantity. As such we cannot use its dimensionality in an argument; it is not zero, but we cannot say what it is. Therefore, we cannot dimensionally derive calculus using these arugments; besides, calculus must hold even in the case of dimensionless quantities!

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Are $c_1$ and $c_2$ functions of $x$? And I don't see how you get from there to "the derivative is any ratio we desire: $\frac{c_1}{c_2}$". As for the point about $dx$, if we make the assumption that a physically meaningful function has a physically meaningful derivative with respect to say time, then we can actually say that since the approximations have a certain dimension, the actual derivative also has the same dimension.

Comment: Dimensional analysis is essentially an assertion of (linear) proportionality. So if $x$ is dimensionally equivalent to some length, then we say it is some scalar multiple of a length unit. This scalar multiple is a constant. Within the limit definition, we have the function proportional to some constant $c_1$, and the "step" term proportional to some (potentially different) constant $c_2$. Since these multiply the numerator and denominator of the limit, respectively, we can "pull them out" and write $f'(x) = \frac{c_1}{c_2} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: Furthermore, $dx$ is not an "approximation." It is many things, but it is not something with finite size, and it is not a proxy for a physical interpretation of approximation.

Comment: You got your quantifiers wrong. Note your own definition which says "**some** scalar multiple", so you cannot treat $c_1$ and $c_2$ as arbitrary. Furthermore you have to multiply the left-hand side by some (fixed but unknown) constant as well otherwise your units are not the same on both sides.

Comment: Secondly, I did not say that $dx$ is an approximation. The derivative is simply the limit of approximations, so if the derivative exists and is physically meaningful, and the approximations are all of some dimension, then the derivative must have the same dimension.

Comment: Not at all; $c_1$ and $c_2$ are indeed arbitrary; they do not take any value until you assign physical meaning to the quantities, which is a different discussion. The Pi theorem holds regardless of what the values are; indeed, the Buckingham Pi theorem is nothing more than computing the basis of the nullspace of an underdetermined linear system; any constant will satisfy it.$${}{}$$
Furthermore, you say "if we make the assumption that a physically meaningful function... that the approximations have a certain dimension." Praytell, how do you bridge the gap from "derivative" to "approximations"?

Comment: (1) No; $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not arbitrary when you want to state equality between quantities, which you did when you claimed that you can get $f'(x)$ being an arbitrary constant times itself. (2) The derivative, if it exists, is a limit of ratios, and each ratio is an approximation of the limit.

Comment: 1.) Yes, of course I state equality. That's the absurdity. The Pi theorem doesn't give us equality, but when we try to carry the pi theorem's results into the definition of a derivative, which asserts equality, you get nonsense. You are confusing the antecedent and the consequent. 2.), The derivative is a limit of a ratio. There are no approximations involved anywhere.

Comment: No I'm not. I know what I am talking about. If it's still not clear to you, you can only say that $c_3 f'(x) = \frac{c_1}{c_2} \lim_{h\to 0} ...$ for some constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$, which gives no contradiction. If you don't like the word "approximation", just replace it in my previous comments with "ratio".

Comment: The point is that the conclusions that we may draw using the Pi theorem get eliminated when we take the limit. If we want to approximate the derivative with a secant, it works. But it does not hold under the limit.

Comment: Well I made myself very clear when I said that we need the assumption that the derivative exists and is physically meaningful, which implies that the secant approximations have the same units as the derivative.

Comment: Maybe you know what you're talking about, but I'm trying to say that your not catching what I'm talking about. I am **not** evaluating the derivative dimensionally. I am **only** asserting dimensionality of the mapping and it's variable, nothing more. If I do those two things and only those two things, the definition of the derivative breaks.

Comment: The existence of a physically meaningful derivative was your hypothesis, not mine. It has no bearing on my argument.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean, but then you're not answering the question! The question isn't saying that we can arbitrarily change dimensions **inside** the derivative. Of course if you change the units used, the numerical component of the derivative can be made to change by an arbitrary ratio, but the question was keeping the units all there, including that of the derivative. That is why the question's argument does work under the assumptions that I mentioned. What you showed does not disprove that argument.

Comment: But the thing is, even if you keep the units the same, the limiting behavior obliterates any sense of maintaining a dimension. This is precisely why the several other examples fail. It doesn't matter if you let meters go to zero or furlongs go to zero, you still get that anomalous behavior resulting from arbitrary constants that don't take values until they are assigned a physical meaning. You cannot presuppose that meaning; the notion of derivative must hold even without a physical context.

Comment: In other words, the Pi theorem gives us a subspace. Physical meaning chooses point in that subspace. But we can't just say, "oh, well get to the physical part eventually, so I can ignore the properties of this subspace that I'm in."

Comment: If the limiting behaviour is the issue, then put that in your answer, since it is indeed an assumption that the asker might not have considered, but the part about arbitrarily setting constants is definitely wrong because the question did not make that mistake. I would say though that it's not a big assumption because if you consider units as indeterminates, then if every approximate of the derivative is a multiple of some unit, the derivative itself would be a multiple of the same unit. Of course it's an assumption, so you can make that clear in your answer, but it's not really objectionable.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
\frac{d}{dx} x^n = c x^{n-1}.
$$

Write this as

$$
\frac{d}{dx} x^p = c(p) x^{p-1},
$$

thus

$$
\frac{d}{dx} x^{p+q} = c(p+q) x^{p+q-1}.
$$

But

$$
\frac{d}{dx} x^{p+q} = \Big( \frac{d}{dx} x^p \Big) x^q + x^p \Big( \frac{d}{dx} x^q \Big) = \Big( c(p) + c(q) \Big) x^{p+q-1},
$$

therefore

$$
c(p+q) = c(p) + c(q),
$$

so we obtain

$$
c(p) = c(1) p.
$$

We also have

$$
\frac{dx}{dx} = 1,
$$

so

$$
c(1) x^0 = 1,
$$

whence

$$
c(1) = 1.
$$

Therefore

$$
c(p) = p,
$$

and we obtain

$$
\frac{d}{dx} x^n = n x^{n-1}.
$$

Comment: Your answer assumes without any justification that the derivative of $x^n$ with respect to $x$ must be a constant times $x^{n-1}$, which is the crux of the question. Also, the later part of your answer is no different from using the product rule to directly prove the desired result, so it has nothing to do with dimensional analysis.

Comment: This follows from dimentional analysis as there are no other dimentionfull constant in the problem therefore $c$ has to be a constant. This solutions gives a way to finding that constant.

Comment: @Winther: Didn't you realize that this solution is nothing but the use of product rule, which could have been done right from the beginning instead of talking about dimensions?